# How to avoid deadlock with threads in C#?

Tags: c#, console, deadlock

I've been creating an asynchronous C# server and the server creates a single thread per client. However, I was told that with too many threads you could end up with deadlock.

So how might avoid deadlock with threads? How would I implement such a feature?

Comment: I recommend you this excellent tutorial about threading in C# http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: Awesome, I'll check this out as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a big topic, to be told here.

Read about it at [Avoid And Detecting Deadlocks in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163618.aspx)

It is a MSDN link

The above link will likely help you

For code samples, click [this link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/7/f279e71e-efb0-4155-873d-5554a0608523/Deadlocks.exe)

Comment: Awesome, although do you have a short code sample of avoiding deadlock? I understand the principle behind it, it'd help more with full sample rather than broken up into a huge topic.

Comment: Oh, very nice! Entire project examples, perfect, thank you for the examples!